# I run crontab in every min but it cannot run the shell and show the result I want

Tags: python, linux, shell, cron, operating-system

I want to run the shell script every min.
Here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
python3 /home/ubuntu/environment/temp.py
```

Here is my temp.py:

```
f= open("temp.txt","w+")
```

Here is my crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh

* * * * * /home/ubuntu/environment/temp.sh
```

However, there is no temp.txt file there after I save the crontab file.

In syslog, it shows:

```
Jul 13 11:58:01 ip-172-31-29-117 CRON[9344]: (ubuntu) CMD (/home/ubuntu/environment/temp.sh)
Jul 13 11:58:01 ip-172-31-29-117 CRON[9345]: (root) CMD (/home/ubuntu/.c9/stop-if-inactive.sh)
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You should try using full directory paths instead of relative paths. Especially when using crontab.

e.g. `f = open ('/home/ubuntu/environment/temp.txt', 'w+')`

Comment: 1. You need the full path to the python interpreter in the virtual environment, for example: `/home/user_name/ve/project_name/bin/python`
2. You need the full path to the python script, for example: `/home/user_name/project_name/script_name.py`
3. cron line: `* * * * /home/user_name/ve/project_name/bin/python /home/user_name/project_name/script_name.py`

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely your current direction when `temp.py` is being run, if it is being run, is what you think it is.  Try writing to `/tmp/temp.txt` so you know where you should be looking.

Also valuable would be checking root's email to see if you have messages from cron about `temp.sh` failing because it doesn't know what this `python3` you speak of is.